# How to enable Web GL in Chrome driver?

Tags: chrome, webgl

I am using selenium to run nightwatch tests. It uses a chrome driver to run the tests. How do I enable Web GL in the chrome driver?

Answer (score -2):

Type `chrome:://flags` in the URL bar, enable "Override software rendering", then relaunch your chromedriver.